# NSArray from subclass v. NSArray in view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have two classes:  `GHHaiku` and `GHViewController`.  In `GHHaiku`, I declare `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayAfterFiltering;`.

In `GHViewController` I instantiate `GHHaiku` as `@property (nonatomic, strong) GHHaiku *ghhaiku;` and then follow it later with this code:

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", cat];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [self.haiku filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];  //haiku is an NSMutableArray property of `GHViewController`
        NSLog(@"%d",filteredArray.count);
```

The NSLog here produces the correct count, 116.

But when I use the following code,

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", cat];
        self.ghhaiku.arrayAfterFiltering = [self.haiku filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"%d",self.ghhaiku.arrayAfterFiltering.count);
```

the NSLog produces a count of 0.

Why is this any different?

Comment: When calling "`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`", what is the count value of "`self.haiku`" in both your separate "`GHHaiku`" & "`GHViewController`" objects?

Comment: In this case it's actually 116--at the moment the filter doesn't filter anything out.  (The idea is that the user will add to the count.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you say that you instantiate `@property (nonatomic, strong) GHHaiku *ghhaiku`. You don't. All you do there is declare the property. So you have a property but the property has no value; it is nil. So `self.ghhaiku` is nil and you are fruitlessly sending messages to nil in your second example.

Comment: AH!  And this is where lazy instantiation comes in!  I'm beginning to understand now....

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the allocation

```
self.ghhaiku.arrayAfterFiltering =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [self.haiku filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```